# GB Test ROM emulation issues

Tags: emulation, gameboy

I've been making a GameBoy emulator, and I'm currently running it through the test ROMs located [here](http://blargg.8bitalley.com/parodius/gb-tests/).

One of the tests in `cpu_instrs.zip` is as follows:

```
set_test 5,"POP AF"
ld   bc,$1200
.loop:
push bc
pop  af
push af
pop  de
ld   a,c
and  $F0
cp   e
jp   nz,test_failed
inc  b
inc  c
jr   nz,.loop
```

From what I understand, it seems like this test will always fail. On the first loop, the zero flag will not be set from `inc c` and then the code will eventually jump to `test_failed` since on the second loop, `e` will equal 1 and `a` will be 0.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems like finding another z80 system/emulator with a debugger where you can step through this would probably be informative.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out that the least significant nibble on the flags register is always zero, and writing a nonzero value to it shouldn't change it.

Comment: Im doing an emulator too and stumbled into the same issue! I actually downloaded another emulator and debugged to find this